# Fieldset HTML Styling using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have 5 fieldsets which I want to layout in a particular design.
All have the same width, but may have different heights.

```
┌-[Fieldset 1]----┐
|                 |
|                 |
└-----------------┘
┌-[Fieldset 2]----┐  ┌-[Fieldset 3]----┐
|                 |  |                 |
|                 |  |                 |
|                 |  |                 |
└-----------------┘  └-----------------┘
┌-[Fieldset 4]----┐  ┌-[Fieldset 5]----┐
|                 |  |                 |
|                 |  |                 |
|                 |  |                 |
|                 |  |                 |
└-----------------┘  └-----------------┘
```

in my HTML source, I want to make the source "clean", which removes any unnecessary formatting tags which include "br" and "p". The container of the fieldsets is set to the full width of the window.

The only way where I can style in it this structure currently, is by placing "br" elements after the fieldsets I want to move to the next line:

```
<fieldset style='width:200px;'><legend>Fieldset1</legend></fieldset><br/>
<fieldset style='width:200px;'><legend>Fieldset2</legend></fieldset>
<fieldset style='width:200px;'><legend>Fieldset3</legend></fieldset><br/>
<fieldset style='width:200px;'><legend>Fieldset4</legend></fieldset>
<fieldset style='width:200px;'><legend>Fieldset5</legend></fieldset>
```

The container which holds the fieldsets is actually the full length of the screen, (ie:100%). If I take out the "br"s the fieldsets line-up next to each other in a haphazard way.

I have tried various ways to align and adjust the fieldsets in the order that I want them using CSS including using float, clear, padding-left but to no avail.

Is there a proper methodology using CSS that can be applied to get the desired effect wanted as shown above?

thankyou.

Answer (score 4):

```
<style type="text/css">
fieldset {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}
</style>

<fieldset><legend>Fieldset1</legend></fieldset>
<fieldset class="clear"><legend>Fieldset2</legend></fieldset>
<fieldset><legend>Fieldset3</legend></fieldset>
<fieldset class="clear"><legend>Fieldset4</legend></fieldset>
<fieldset><legend>Fieldset5</legend></fieldset>
```

Comment: Whoops, had just noticed I forgot to plug in the clear class instead of the inline styles. :)

Comment: tried applying your style to my page and it did not work. It lined the fieldsets 1 to 5 across the top of the screen. I cut and pasted your code into a clean page, and I got the same effect with the layout that i got. i am currently using IE7.

Comment: Did you use the version after the update? I had a typo in there.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
.fld{float:left;}
.fld1{float:left;}
```

class .fld for 2 and 3rd fieldset.
class .fld1 for 4 and 5 fieldset.

Here is the working example:http://jsfiddle.net/anish/xaZDC/

Answer (score 0):

If you want all but the first fieldset to flow use Anishs answe, if you always want a 1-2-2-2 etc lay out [see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CdNNY/)

**EDIT**
Just noticed this is almost identical to dtbarne's answer. Accept his and use mine to see it in action